# I'm trying to print the properties of a class using a prototype method, but it's not working

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and this is what I tried to do, I took a recipe and then by using the prototype, I added a method to be inherited by all the classes/objects that I define.

But it's not working... :C

Here is what I have :

```
function Recipe(name, origin, auther, ingredients, directions) {
  this.name = name;
  this.origin = origin;
  this.author = auther;
  this.ingredients = ingredients;
  this.directions = directions;
};

Recipe.prototype.printRecipe(){
  return "<ul>" + "<li>" + this.name + "</li>" + "<li>" + this.origin + "</li>" + "<li>" + this.author + "</li>" + "<li>" + this.ingredients + "</li>" + "<li>" + this.directions + "</li>" +"</ul>";
}

var Salad = new Recipe("Fruit Salad", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Apples, Bananas, Berries, Milk, Sugar, Dry fruits", "<ul><li>sdasds</li></ul>")

document.getElementById("text").innerHTML =  Salad.printRecipe();
```

**Edit:** Fixed so all code will be formatted as code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is syntax adding property:

`SomeClass.prototype.propertyName = "property";`

And this is syntax adding method:

`SomeClass.prototype.methodName = function() {
    return this.property;
};`

So you should write your code like this:

```
Recipe.prototype.printRecipe = function(){
  return "<ul>" + "<li>" + this.name + "</li>" + "<li>" + this.origin + "</li>" + "<li>" + this.author + "</li>" + "<li>" + this.ingredients + "</li>" + "<li>" + this.directions + "</li>" +"</ul>";
};
```

Comment: OHHHH Thanks alot! :D

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is add a method to your `prototype`, so you should do:

```
function Recipe(name, origin, auther, ingredients, directions) {
  this.name = name;
  this.origin = origin;
  this.author = auther;
  this.ingredients = ingredients;
  this.directions = directions;
};

// Note how we changed the syntax of this line slightly and added the 'function' word
Recipe.prototype.printRecipe = function(){
  return "<ul>" + "<li>" + this.name + "</li>" + "<li>" + this.origin + "</li>" + "<li>" + this.author + "</li>" + "<li>" + this.ingredients + "</li>" + "<li>" + this.directions + "</li>" +"</ul>";
}

var Salad = new Recipe("Fruit Salad", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Apples, Bananas, Berries, Milk, Sugar, Dry fruits", "<ul><li>sdasds</li></ul>")

document.getElementById("text").innerHTML =  Salad.printRecipe();
```

You can use the [W3Schools Javascript course](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp) to learn more about prototypes and see examples